# OS X: update draw during fullscreen animation

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I am currently programmatically enabling fullscreen in an OS X 10.7+ app, via the techniques described in [this apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html), that uses OpenGL to renderer its views.  Is it possible to enable per-frame screen updates during the full screen animation?  Currently, it seems like a screenshot is taken before and after fullscreen is entered and there is an automatic alpha fade between the two.

I would like to instead redraw the content at every frame so that there is a smooth fade between the two sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at the Custom Full-Screen Presentation Animations section in [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentation